# Как реализовать сохранение состояния моделей представления на диск в AvaloniaUI?

Tags: c#, .net, avalonia

Всем привет!

Решил поковырять Avonia. Столкнулся с проблемой сохранения состояния моделей представления на диск. В сети гуляет по разным сайтам копипаст одной и той же [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/post/457164/). Собственно по ней и делал.

В статье сказано:

> Приведённая выше реализация ISuspensionDriver при первом запуске и
> выключении приложения создаст файл состояния с именем appstate.json

Но при запуске получаю ошибку **FileNotFoundException**, со ссылкой на тот самый файл **appstate.json**

Думал может быть что-то не так делаю. Скачал готовый пример с [github](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/main/avalonia/suspension/ReactiveUI.Samples.Suspension), и все та же ошибка.

В гугле ничего кроме этой статьи и примера в документациях Avalonia и ReactiveUI (код в которых аналогичен) не нашел.

Может кто сталкивался или подскажет альтернативные решения?

Comment: из статьи `System.IO не работает с Universal Winows Platform, но это легко исправить — достаточно вместо File и Directory использовать StorageFile и StorageFolder` может из-за этого?

Comment: @Bulson платформа определенно не UWP. В проекте есть файл appstate.json, и если его скопировать, то конечно же работает. Но не генерировать же самостоятельно, не должно так быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается все просто. Достаточно выполнить сборку проекта/решения, а затем запустить приложение в ручную. После чего заветный файл будет сгенерирован, и при отладке ошибки больше не будет, сохранение состояния работает.